# TypeScript: Change return type based on another type from an object

Tags: typescript

So what I am trying to do is demonstrated by the following working code:

```
type Records = {
  user: {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    age: number;
  },
  device: {
    id: string;
    brand: string;
    manufacturer: string;
  }
}

function getRecord (record: keyof Records, id: number) {
  return {} as Records['user']; // this is bad, should be a variable instead of hard coded.
}

const record = getRecord1('user', 123);
//    ^ becomes a user type
```

However, as you can see on the `getRecord` function, I have to hard-code the return as `Records['user']`, what I want is for it to be a variable such that the return type becomes the type of a property inside of `Records`, I'm trying to achieve this flexibility by deriving the return type of the function from its arguments, but I can't seem to find a way to do that, as demonstrated by the non-working code below.

```
type Records = {
  user: {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    age: number;
  },
  device: {
    id: string;
    brand: string;
    manufacturer: string;
  }
}

function getRecord (record: keyof Records, id: number) {
  return {} as Records[typeof record]; // unfortunately I can't do Records[record]
}

const record = getRecord('user', 123);
//     ^ Should become Records.user type, but it doesn't
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert this function to a generic one:

```
function getRecord<T extends keyof Records>(record: T, id: number): Records[T] {
  return {} as Records[T];
}

const record = getRecord('user', 123);
```

See [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=9&module=100&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGB7ATgEwM5QLxQN4FgAoKKAV3QmQC48iSSBLVG9YZBgOwHMBuO%20jgEMAthBZtOvfiUFcxUDqWEAjSn2JQAvgBp%20qCADcG8eQQ2NmUVu27r6UZckEdL1yXfrDnpAGaD4wKTIlOI2UhqaRJGERD6kHAEMiBxQcsBwSGgAPAAqUBAAHsAQLpgA1hAgiD6wCCgYAHwAFMGZljnaUEw0iiqUAJQ0GfXoANo5ALq0GsGByCm4mlCCmMNoY5Pq0URIHKxQrfXYqRDpdWhNAOTklJedAIwATADM-epAA)

Comment: yep, this was actually answered in the ts discord but forgot to post the answer here. Thanks!